# Get item contains substring Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have the feollowing variable in my code:

```
variable "mylist" {
  default = ["cardigan.com", "crazy-apple.com", "blue-pen.com"]
}
```

On a creation of given resource, I have to pass the name of element in this list according to a substring. How can a retrieve the element of this list that contains the substring "apple", for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A collect/filter/map family function also does not exist yet in Terraform. We therefore can use a `for` expression lambda with a conditional inside a list constructor:

```
[ for item in var.my_list : item if can(regex("apple", item)) ]
```

and this returns `["crazy-apple.com"]` for your example variable value. You can then access its elements to return the string e.g. `crazy-apple.com` as per normal. If you are using >= 0.15, and are very confident only one match exists, then you could also do:

```
one([ for item in var.my_list : item if can(regex("apple", item)) ])
```

to directly return `crazy-apple.com`.

Comment: Thank you, Matt! It worked for me.